# Which conditions would trigger error handling in "read_line" followed by "expect"?

Tags: rust

When reading the input stream with `read_line()`, if you don't follow the statement with a `.expect()` the compiler will warn you that `` this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled ``.

What I want to understand is what kind of situation will trigger such error handling.

I've tried piping my program into another one (`./my_program | echo "hello"`) so I wouldn't have the chance to enter any input and would supposedly be able to see the error handling in action. To my surprise it actually led to a panic state:

`thread 'main' panicked at 'failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)', src/libstd/io/stdio.rs:792:9`

In this code from the book [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html), we specify a string which I believe should be printed when the program isn't able to read the input stream:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

How can I actually see that behavior in action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's follow the source:

- [`std::io::Stdin::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#320-322) delegates to `std::io::StdinLock::read_line`.
- [`std::io::StdinLock::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#1849-1854) delegates to a private [`append_to_string` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#328).
- `append_to_string` returns an error on non-UTF-8 input.

Let's try this:

```sh
$ rustc a.rs # your program
$ echo "\x99" | ./a
Guess the number!
Please input your guess.
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to read line: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: StringError("stream did not contain valid UTF-8") }', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Comment: Very complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately `echo "\x99" | ./a` does not work. By that I mean it doesn't fail.

Comment: @RamyHerrira This works (that is, the program fails the expected way) for me with rustc 1.57.0, with zsh, on Linux. Bash however passes a literal `\` followed by `x99` instead of the expected byte. Looks like Bash changes the behaviour of `\xNN` depending on whether the sequence would be a valid UTF-8 character or not…

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Thanks !

Comment: The comment above was meant to read "a literal ``\`` followed by `x99`", somehow escaping ``\`` is not the expected backslash-backslash.